# Fluorescence photons per event

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fluorescence

When a high-energy photon hits a material that fluoresces, what formula can you use to determine how many photons will radiate out  as the material de-excites?
I would like the most general formula that you can identify all the terms in.

Comment: The question sounds too generic. What kind of material do you consider. Organic molecules? Or an isolated atom? For a simple two-level system, there is a relatively simple formula, but things grow quickly in complexity, as you add more levels. The reason is that your fluorescent material can de-excite to different states with different branching ratios, and some states will be "dark" to your incident light (won't respond).

Comment: The material is glass. I expect it will be pretty cold, as a satellite.

Comment: I can understand glass will scatter photons elastically, (Rayleigh scattering)  but never heard of glass fluorescing. Any reference on that?

Comment: @IamAStudent Leaded glass is (or at least was) a common choice for calorimeters because the high mass-density leads to smaller devices. For efficient scintillation it needs enough lead that it (a) has a distinct yellow-green tint and (b) even quite small blocks are shockingly heavy in the hand. Other dopants can also generate scintillation or fluorescence.